# Cache memory issue mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, backbone.js

i'm developing an app by backbone and db on parse.com.
I've written an alert code to print the user(2 only user) into db:by browser the app alert correctly the two user that are in db but by mobile device (android) are alerted 5 user,the previous number of user in db but after deleted!
How can it is possible?How can fit it?

Comment: Have you checked your parse.com dashboard to verify you deleted your users?

Comment: yes are deleted, starting app by browser works correctly